# Primefaces Ajax components issue

Tags: primefaces

FrameWork: Primefaces 3.4.2

Issue:
  My code has one Non-ajax command button and two Ajax command buttons. When I submit the form through the Non-ajax button, once the page is loaded again ( Came to same page with updating some other data). Now If I click on the Ajax buttons they are not working.

Comment: Please add the report.xhtml content

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have forgot about the `update=""` attribute, but it is hard to tell if you don't attach your code.